# Can't download Google Chrome on my Mac!

Tags: macos, safari, imac, google-chrome

I'm on the page http://google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html

There is a large blue button "Download Chrome" and below it "For Mac OS X 10.6 or later".

I click on the button. Result: the whole screen goes gray, and all links are de-activated, like a "lightbox" effect, and nothing else?!

Safari Version 8.0 (10600.1.25) On a Mac OS X Yosemite Version 10.10 iMac 27-inch

Comment: Did you try rebooting? You should get a pop-up with terms to accept next, then the download after that.

Comment: your safari's out of date, btw, though idk if that makes any difference; as is your OS, if that really is 10.10.0 then that would be first thing to do, get it up to date.

Comment: My OS it out of date? I'm really surprised, because this is a brand new 3-month old computer!

Comment: I did try rebooting. Didn't help.

Comment: Check System Prefs > App Store. I'm guessing you have Updates switched off. Or look at the App Store app itself & select the Updates tab at the top. There have been 2 bugfix Yosemite releases since 10.10.0 - current is 10.10.2 - also updates to Safari, current is 8.0.3 (10600.3.18).

Comment: In my case it was the AdBlock safari plugin, I had to disable it for the chrome installed to start downloading.

Answer (score 4):

Try downloading Chrome from the command line instead. [This solution](https://superuser.com/questions/602680/how-to-install-google-chrome-from-the-command-line) has the command to download Chrome AND install.

solutions outlined are:

**Using Homebrew cask**

```
brew install brew-cask
brew install --cask google-chrome
```

**Using wget command**

```
wget https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg
open ~/Downloads/googlechrome.dmg
sudo cp -r /Volumes/Google\ Chrome/Google\ Chrome.app /Applications/
```

**Alternatively**, using your browser, you can go to the direct link [HERE](https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg) and the browser will download the file automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Solution: Safari allowed me to download firefox, and from firefox I was able to download chrome!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was a wrong date in MacOS. After updating the date and time in my machine, I was able to download google chrome correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome offline installer for Mac

https://www.google.com/chrome/#eula
https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg